# Google Analytics Email Tracking how to fetch the cid to include in the tracking url on email templates

Tags: analytics

I am trying to include the google analytics read email tracking on my mailer, I have to include one image url in the page like below

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-3333333-1&cid=CLIENT_ID_NUMBER&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=recipient_id&cs=Newsletter1&cm=email&cn=My%20test%20prod%201

Everything except cid value is fine. It is mandatory and as we cannot use the javascript here to create a random number for this, please help me by telling how can I include the cid in the tracking url

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the cid before the email get's sent

or host the pixel image on your server and use your own end point to communicate to google